# BULK INSERT - header and data rows with different delimiters

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I'm using the following BULK INSERT command

```
BULK INSERT dbo.A
FROM 'd:\AData.csv'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',ROWTERMINATOR = ',\n',FIRSTROW = 2)
```

to process the data shown. My import skips the first row but also skips the second row. In this case i believe this is because my header and data rows have different delimiters,the data rows have a training comma.

```
DATASET 1
Trial,Timestep,Column1    - line 1
1,0,0,- line 2
1,1,0.00687237750794734, - line 3
1,2,-0.00190074803257245,- line 4
```

The import works with this data (note the comma on line 1)

```
DATASET 2
Trial,Timestep,Column1,    - line 1
1,0,0,- line 2
1,1,0.00687237750794734, - line 3
1,2,-0.00190074803257245,- line 4
```

Is there a way to tweak the parameters of the BULK INSERT command to handle DATASET1 without using a custom formatting file?

Comment: AFIK, this is not possible. Header and other rows must have same terminator. A conditional terminator is not possible. Remove the Header row from your file altogether then it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Delete header row from your file and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Your data rows have a comma at the end, but your header row doesn't. Get rid of the last commas in the data rows and try again.